# integration Paytm Payment Gateway Android

Tags: java, android, payment-gateway, paytm

I am trying to integrate paytm's payment gateway to my Android App. I can't seem to find any proper documentations or procedures on their website. I've checked every lead on this through google but no help. Tried contacting the Paytm team through mail and phone .. no response. now I am stuck here.

here's what I am passing :

```
paramMap.put("REQUEST_TYPE", "DEFAULT");
paramMap.put("ORDER_ID", String.valueOf(randomInt));
paramMap.put("MID", "************2343");
paramMap.put("CUST_ID", "CUST123");
paramMap.put("CHANNEL_ID", "WAP");
paramMap.put("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID", "Retail");
paramMap.put("WEBSITE", "frshlrfowap");
paramMap.put("TXN_AMOUNT", "1");
paramMap.put("EMAIL", "testing@gmail.com");
paramMap.put("MOBILE_NO", "9876543210");
paramMap.put("THEME", "merchant");
```

Below is the **Error** in output log I am getting:
[image: project output log]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342477/oops-payment-failed-due-to-any-of-this-reasons-when-trying-to-call-paytm-servi/47899946#47899946

Comment: Check my ans here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342477/oops-payment-failed-due-to-any-of-this-reasons-when-trying-to-call-paytm-servi/47899946#47899946

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, Finally I was able to get through. 
Most Importantly you need to get in touch with Paytm's Ops team. Contact the person who provided the Key & ID's and he will lead to the Tech/ops team. Share Logs with them.

mail them on: cmt.ops@paytm.com & tech.ops@paytm.com

For Paytm, setup Merchant Key on server side files **(verifyChecksum.php & generateChecksum.php)**. My Issue was, My client provided different Merchant Key (may be Sandbox one) which lead me to "Client Authentication failed". After Sharing Logs with their team they provided the Correct Key and I started getting correct response from the server. **Also, check for INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID" with the support guys.**  Wrong INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID" will lead you to the different error.

Good Luck!!

Comment: so you need to have your backend set for this ? Can this be done just by android ?

Comment: Cant we use default checksum url provided by paytm?

Answer (score 2):

To integrate paytm on android app please add dependency in gradle file

```
// paytm dependency
    implementation('com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.2.3') {
        transitive = true;
    }
```

Add Paytm Activity in android menifest file

```
<activity android:name="com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmPGActivity"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard"/>
```

To generate checksum you don't need to pass email id  and mobile number.You should pass only 8 param as below-

```
    String url ="https://www.blueappsoftware.com/payment/payment_paytm/generateChecksum.php";
    String varifyurl = "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCallback.jsp";

 String param=
                    "MID="+mid+
                    "&ORDER_ID=" + orderId+
                    "&CUST_ID="+custid+
                    "&CHANNEL_ID=WAP&TXN_AMOUNT=100&WEBSITE=WEBSTAGING"+
                            "&CALLBACK_URL="+ varifyurl+"&INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID=Retail";
```

Please check this reference link. You can find step by step process on this reference link- [https://www.blueappsoftware.com/paytm-payment-gateway-integration-android-studio/](https://www.blueappsoftware.com/paytm-payment-gateway-integration-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

Go to [here](https://www.studytutorial.in/paytm-payment-gateway-integrating-in-android). Got the full paytm integration in android

Steps for Integration

1. Add dependency in the project
2. Add SMS Permission
3. Generate Checksum
4. Verify Checksum

Answer (score 0):

according to my info you need authentication permissions from paytm without this you may not use it try to get it first. or the simple way is use webview and embed paytm link in it and let the user directly interact with it.

Comment: I believe we have the authentication permissions as we have the merchant ID which is being used at the website for payments. We got sdk & UIs from Paytm. We have to call the paytm activity class with proper params. 
Webview is not the solution but an alternative .. I want to make it native.

Comment: as you can see to use google accounts or facebook you have api's and you get keys on registration which allows you to communicate with them... the paytm is a individual application so you require this key or authentication for it.. just like google and fb. i think directly you cant communicate over

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer :

Go and open this [link](http://paywithpaytm.com/developer.html).

1) Download Android+SDK

2) After downloading it , you will get **pgsdk.jar** in it and also put in your project folder.

3) Now put their code.

4) In their code, they ask for ChecksumGenerator  and ValidateChksum URL which are for testing purpose. You can get it by contacting to paytm development support team and they will give you checksum generation and checksum validation code including merchant id and all necessary things that you need to deploy in your server.

And after successfully integration might be your problem get solved.

See Below link for Knowing some facts regarding PayTm.

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-integrate-Paytm-wallet-in-an-Android-application-as-a-payment-option-just-like-in-the-Uber-app

Comment: yeah .. I've done this procedure exactly in the first time. 
Problem is "Client Authentication failed. Please try again later" message I am getting after passing the above parameters..

Comment: Have you provided all the information correctly ? As i have wroked with it try to provide valid Customer ID.

Comment: well, I tried providing all the valid information from the database. Still returns me the same error message.

Comment: In this case you need to contact PayTm support becasue they haven't provided any Open Document for this.