# "OOPS payment failed due to any of this reasons" when trying to call paytm service

Tags: android

I am integrating paytm in my android app using this documentation:
[PAYTM integration in android app](http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/paytm_sdk_doc?target=how-paytm-sdk-works)

but when I am clicking on pay with PAYTM button it is showing following error:

> Payment failed due to any of these reasons:
>
> - Session expired due to inactivity
> - Our system encountered an obstacle
>
> You can fix it yourself! Here’s how:
>
> - Clear cookies & temporary internet files of the browser
> - Check payment status with your bank to avoid double payment
> - Launch a new browser & start from the beginning
> - Still unable to transact? visit us at paytm.com/care

I am using PHP for backend services as provided in PAYTM documentation.

I am using send box credentials right now for testing purpose.

MID :***************45797

Merchant key : ************vIM1

Comment: you are working with test details or live details? Also, check which MID you are using and this error occurred due to checksum mismatch.

Comment: I am working on test details. And I have cross verified my MID using PAYTM discussion forum.

Comment: I have find that this error response 403 comes when Incorrect response from bank. Also, you can find response code in this [paytm response codes](http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/paytm_api_doc?target=response-codes).

Comment: can add your code here?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution for all :

Be sure to send equal number of parameters to your server (For checksum generator) And then to paytm server for payment.

For example:
    If you are sending 6 params for checksum generator, then send these 6 same parameters including Checksum to Paytm...
    It will resolve your problem.

**CODE EXAMPLE :**

```
#Generate checksum.php

$paramList = array();
$paramList["MID"] = 'Provided by Paytm'; //Provided by Paytm
$paramList["ORDER_ID"] = 'hIquwhzvzTG7gvT'; //unique OrderId for every request
$paramList["CUST_ID"] = 'CUST0001453'; // unique customer identifier
$paramList["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = 'Retail'; //Provided by Paytm
$paramList["CHANNEL_ID"] = 'WAP'; //Provided by Paytm
$paramList["TXN_AMOUNT"] = '10.00'; // transaction amount
$paramList["WEBSITE"] = 'APP_STAGING';//Provided by Paytm
$paramList["CALLBACK_URL"] = 'https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCallback.jsp';

#Android Activity.java

paramMap.put("MID" , "#########");
paramMap.put( "ORDER_ID" , "hIquwhzvzTG7gvT");
paramMap.put( "CUST_ID" , "CUST0001453");
paramMap.put( "CHANNEL_ID" , "WAP");
paramMap.put( "TXN_AMOUNT" , "10.00");
paramMap.put( "WEBSITE" , "APP_STAGING");
paramMap.put( "CALLBACK_URL" , "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCallback.jsp");
paramMap.put( "CHECKSUMHASH" , "dR5OtEkuNkgamHTZDCHmF+CF3j9RdG1520mlHEb85oSZP1CaxVUsRY2sYric90HLm/vElaPZKoQ7b5/SyFpi3oBWXf2BQNy+r6iiBwg4AH4=");
paramMap.put("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID" , "Retail");
```

**NOTE :** Please keep in mind to send paytm server exact parameters plus one checksum.....