# Paytm Integration not working android

Tags: android, android-studio, paytm

Paytm Integration not working. I have tried several examples but all of them are showing the same error, even its sample demo at its official site is showing the same Oops error.

It redirects to Oops, Payment failed due to any of these reasons page while logging with testing credentials. I even tried with my own real debit card credentials but it results in the same error.

Testing credentials:

- Phone No: 7777777777
- Password:Paytm1XXXXXX

[[image: below is the screen shot]

Comment: Check my ans here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342477/oops-payment-failed-due-to-any-of-this-reasons-when-trying-to-call-paytm-servi/47899946#47899946

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue in [Android](http://smarther.co/android-app-development-company/) Nougat, please update the Chrome Browser — to the latest version (V55)

Also — we recommend you to set it to -auto-update but clicking on the three vertical dots on the right hand side.

Once you do the update — please kill and re-open the Paytm app and try adding money now.

Comment: i used mash mellow device i don't have nougat how to resolved this issue please help me

Answer (score 1):

Have u got all the parameters from paytm? like MID, WEBSITE, MERCHANT KEY etc. If yes then first and foremost thing you should do is, talk or mail to a Paytm representative allotted to your paytm account.

Second, if you have all the parameters, talk to paytm support for configuring your checksum generation and validation urls. They usually don't configure it properly and it is the most common cause for this error.

Third, they recently changed their flow for server side implementation, so ask your back-end tech person about the update, if he had or not implemented the changes.